# Converting JavaScript data to JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am using the following code to dynamically add items to a page. I have each component as an object then I call each individual one with a For-in loop.
My question is, how can I convert my data to JSON, and then import it into my JS file to use?

```
const pageObjects = {
  objectComponent1 : {
    provideTitle: "Title",
    provideId: "title",
    provideDesc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices. Id aliquet risus feugiat in. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at. ",
    provideHtml: `<p class="test">This is a pragraph element.</p>`,
  },
  objectComponent2: {
    provideTitle: "Title",
    provideId: "title",
    provideDesc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse ultrices. Id aliquet risus feugiat in. Eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur purus. Non consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna duis. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at.",
    provideHtml: `<p class="test">This is a pragraph element.</p>`,
  },
};

const docsContent = document.querySelector(".docs-content");

for (const singleObject in pageObjects) {
  // add title
  let objectTitle = document.createElement("h2");
  objectTitle.setAttribute("id", pageObjects[singleObject].provideId);
  objectTitle.innerHTML = pageObjects[singleObject].provideTitle;
  docsContent.append(objectTitle);

  // add description
  let objectDesc = document.createElement("p");
  objectDesc.innerHTML = pageObjects[singleObject].provideDesc;
  docsContent.append(objectDesc);

  // add example
  let objectExample = document.createElement("div");
  objectExample.classList.add("docs-example");
  objectExample.innerHTML = pageObjects[singleObject].provideHtml;
  docsContent.append(objectExample);

  // add provide code
  let objectCode = document.createElement("div");
  objectCode.classList.add("docs-code");
  docsContent.append(objectCode);
  let pre = document.createElement("pre");
  objectCode.append(pre);
  let code = document.createElement("code");
  code.innerHTML =  pageObjects[singleObject].provideHtml;
  pre.append(code);  
};
```

Comment: There's really only one way to convert JS data structures to JSON and that's [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). It's not exactly clear what you're asking though. What have you tried? Is there anywhere you're stuck?

Comment: My plan is to place my data in another file, the for-in loop will live in its own file. I was thinking that the file with my data should be json, but it sounds like I may have to keep it js.

Comment: There are many ways to do this... store your `pageObjects` as plain old JS data in another file and include it via `<script>` as a global variable; export it from a [JS module file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) and import it into your main module; store it as JSON and load it via AJAX;

Comment: Looks like JS modules is the way to go. Thanks.